# R keep only last submission?

Tags: r

My data looks something like this:

```
DF<- data.frame( id=c("A1","A2","A3","A1"), submission=c(1,1,1,2))
```

What is the best way of keeping only the last submission for each id? That is:

```
DF<- data.frame( id=c("A2","A3","A1"), submission=c(1,1,2))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few options in base R:

```
DF[!duplicated(DF$id, fromLast=TRUE),]
#   id submission
# 2 A2          1
# 3 A3          1
# 4 A1          2

do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF$id, FUN=tail, 1))
#    id submission
# A1 A1          2
# A2 A2          1
# A3 A3          1

aggregate(submission ~ id, DF, tail, 1)
#   id submission
# 1 A1          2
# 2 A2          1
# 3 A3          1
```

Comment: That was easier than what I had in mind. If i understand correctly, first I need to order the data frame  by submission?

Comment: @Ignacio, Yes. I had assumed this was the case to begin with.

Comment: another, albeit less elegant construct that I found interesting was:
w<-tapply(DF$submission, DF$id, max)
and then subset(DF, submission==w[id])